quill editor new update changed image uploader and link ui in toolbar
so this code: 
                            <span class="ql-formats mr-0">
                                <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                                <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                                <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                                <button class="ql-image"></button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <button class="ql-link"></button>
                                <select class="ql-color"></select>
                                <select class="ql-background"></select>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
                                <button class="ql-header" value="2"></button>
                                <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
                                <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ql-formats mg-t-5">
                                <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                                <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
                                <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
                                <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

/**START INIT THE QL EDITOR */
var editorEl_cases_description = $("#message-editor-compose .editor");
// Email compose Editor
if (editorEl_cases_description.length) {
  var caseDescriptionEditor = new Quill(editorEl_cases_description[0], {
    bounds: "#message-editor-compose .editor",
    modules: {
      //formula: true,
      syntax: true,
      toolbar: ".compose-editor-toolbar-edit-compose",
    },
    placeholder: "Description",
    theme: "snow",
  });
}
/**END INIT THE QL EDITOR */

is used to create a quill editor with the toolbar, it works but when i lick on the image button or link button it alerts a (add image url) or (add link), instead for the image i want to open the windows folders like a regular input and for the link it used to open an input field to add the url
this happened right after i uploaded the new version of ql, how can i fix this
